# How do I configured postfix and to use SES, and still be able to forward email from unverified external addresses?

Tags: amazon-ec2, postfix, amazon-ses

We are using postfix for email group lists (eg "members@domain.com" will go to all members) from Amazon EC2 systems.  For a variety of reasons (scalability and reliability) we would like to use SES for all outgoing emails.

I was able to configure postfix to use SES as the SMTP for outgoing emails.  This works fine for all verified emails.  But of course, when an outsider emails me at "jeff@domain.com", it chokes.  Postfix is configured to forward to my gmail account (via the virtual table), the SES rejects it because the outside user is not verified.

So none of our mailing groups configured through postfix will work this way.

I would be happy to rewrite all "From" addresses before sending (and simply leave the Reply To as the original sender), but I cannot seem to find a working configuration.

No matter what I set in canonical or generic regexps, SES seems to reject all forwarded emails.

Surely somebody must have configured postfix with SES to handle virtual addresses?  How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Verified emails? Have you turned on "prod mode" for your SES? Out of the box, SES nly lets you send to verified emails. Look for the button for production access. You fill out a form, and they remove that restriction.